# Search data from Multiple table based on a search form FIELDS

Tags: php, sql

Well, I've a search form which have many field like...Html Dropdown selected fields and many Checkbox fields.

So i want to search data from **mysql database multiple table** based on the form. In this form **I can select only drop down box or I can select all Checkbox or I can select few checkbox.**

So that I'm using following sql query to get the data. It's only showing 1 table data. I need to get data from multiple table. What is the sql query should look like ?

```
    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tutor_signup_form WHERE gender = '$gender' OR feerange <= '$budget' ");
    $num =  mysql_num_rows($search);
```

**Database Table with Column Name:**

```
tutor_signup_form        (id, gender, feerange, name, fname, lname)
tutor_signup_edu_olevel  (id, o_psd, o_diploma, o_degree)
tutor_signup_edu_alevel  (id, a_psd, a_diploma, a_degree)
tutor_signup_edu_diploma (id, d_psd, d_diploma, d_degree)
tutor_signup_edu_degree  (id, dig_psd, dig_diploma, dig_degree)
```

Thanks for your suggestion or Help!

**Update:**

```
// search gender    
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . *, tutor_signup_edu_olevel . *, tutor_signup_edu_alevel . *, tutor_signup_edu_diploma . *, tutor_signup_edu_degree . *, tutor_signup_edu_masters . *, tutor_signup_edu_psd . *, tutor_signup_level_primary . *, tutor_signup_level_olevel . *, tutor_signup_level_alevel . *, tutor_signup_level_int . *, tutor_signup_level_uni . *, tutor_signup_level_music . *, tutor_signup_level_lang . *, tutor_signup_level_com . *, tutor_signup_pre_central . *, tutor_signup_pre_east . *, tutor_signup_pre_west . *, tutor_signup_pre_south . *, tutor_signup_pre_north . *, tutor_signup_pre_ne . *, tutor_signup_pre_nw . *  FROM tutor_signup_form

INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id     
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_alevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_alevel.tutor_id 
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_diploma ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_diploma.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_degree ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_degree.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_masters ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_masters.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psd ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_psd.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_primary ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_primary.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_olevel.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_alevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_alevel.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_int ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_int.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_uni ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  tutor_signup_level_uni.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_music ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_music.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_lang ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_level_lang.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_level_com ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  tutor_signup_level_com.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_central ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_central.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_east ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_east.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_west ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_west.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_south ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_south.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_north ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  tutor_signup_pre_north.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_ne ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_ne.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_pre_nw ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_pre_nw.tutor_id 
WHERE tutor_signup_form.feerange <= '$budget' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on [MYSQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

As an example:

```
$query="select A.gender,B.o_psd from tutor_signup_form as A,tutor_signup_edu_olevel as B where A.id=B.id"; //just an example condition
```

Comment: arunrc... May be I've to join all table first then I need to use where clause. Am I right ?

Comment: Just fetch the columns as in simple mysql query. But use a unique name(like A,B etc. in example) to represent each table.

Comment: Join the tables you want, then use the where clause if required.

Comment: Check my updated question. Now why it's not working ?

Comment: first of all, using the table name itself won't be good, since it makes query weird. You can use simple variables.
 
Here what is your condition in ON? You are comparing _this table=that table_. You want to check _a value of this table column=a value of that table column_

Comment: Now the query is working but I'm getting 24 results. But it's should be 3 results because In tutor_signup_form have 3 row which match the where clause. I'm using `DISTINCT`but it's not working.

Comment: any idea ? for test purpose I used while to see the number id. It's showing me 24 id but it's should be 3 based on my where clause criteria. I used `DISTINCT` IS IT OK ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59916/discussion-between-arunrc-and-shibbir).